# AngularJS ng-selected ng-repeat multi-dimension

Tags: angularjs

i try to make a table with with an select each row. the data from table and the select field is from an array...

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Headline #1</th>
            <th>Headline #2</th>
            <th>Headline #3</th>
            <th>Headline #4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{user.id}}</td>
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>
                <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="" ng-repeat="role in roles">{{role.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>anything...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.users = [
            {
                id : 1,
                name : 'Andrew',
                role : "admin"
            },
            {
                id : 2,
                name : 'Tanya',
                role : "admin"
            },
            {
                id : 3,
                name : 'Roland',
                role : "author"
            },
        ];

        $scope.roles = [
            {
                name : "author"
            },
            {
                name : "admin"
            }

        ];



});
```

see my example here: 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JFUrL/4/)

what i need is simple, each user has an role, and i would like that each row the correct role is selected...

sorry for my very bad english...

thx nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `id` field for the roles data list like this

```
$scope.roles = [{
    id: "author",
    name: "author"
}, {
    id: "admin",
    name: "admin"
}];
```

and change `select` element to

```
<select ng-model="user.role" ng-options="role.id as role.name for role in roles"></select>
```

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dr3Kn/)**</kbd>

Comment: You don't need to add an id field. You can just use `role.name` instead of a new `role.id`. See http://jsfiddle.net/MKb4N/